# jQuery allow only numbers and fullstop

Tags: jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".qty").keydown(function (event) {
                 // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
                 if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
                     // Allow: Ctrl+A
                     (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                     // Allow: home, end, left, right
                     (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                     // let it happen, don't do anything
                     return;
                 }
                 else {
                     // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                     if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                         event.preventDefault();
                     }
                 }
             });
         });

</script>
```

the above code accepts only numbers, I would like to accept numbers and fullstop(.)

isn't keycode for . 46??

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just running a regex `onblur`?

Comment: `'.'.charCodeAt(0)` returns 46, but inside the keydown handler in Windows/Chrome it is 190. Weird stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 110
```

Comment: How did you find this 110? I can't find it anywhere. I've pressed every button but the 'sleep' button on my keyboard.

Comment: You can also use `[46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110].indexOf(event.keyCode) !== -1`.

Comment: @Sanchit http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: It tells me 190 when I try it out but the chart says 110. Strange. My keyboard manufacturer is messing with me I suppose.

Comment: SO BASICALLY your code will never work for me, as I don't have any button on my keyboard with keyCode 110. Regex is the only correct way to do it then I suppose.

Comment: Regex is the correct way to do but this is for an assignment I must use jQuery thats why.

Comment: You can use jQuery and regexes. jQuery doesn't forbid you from using a regex. If this is a homework assignment do let your teacher/professor know that this code isn't exactly portable.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it with a regex on blur:

```
$('.qty').on('blur', function () {
    $(this).val(function (i, v) {
        return v.replace(/[^a-z.]/ig, '');
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfrUx/

---

If you can let go for a minute of the *I must use jQuery* mentality, then use this:

```
$('.qty').on('blur', function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z.]/ig, '');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfrUx/1/

Answer (score 0):

They keycode for `.` seems to be 190 for me.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('input.textbox').keydown(function(event){console.log(event.keyCode);}); });` I typed this into the chrome console and used the searchbox in stackoverflow. It returned 190. :[